# Unable to overwrite the return address to create stackoverflow

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, stack-overflow, x86-64

I am trying out an example from the book [The Shellcoder's Handbook: Discovering and Exploiting Security Holes, 2nd Edition](https://www.wiley.com/en-as/The+Shellcoder%27s+Handbook%3A+Discovering+and+Exploiting+Security+Holes%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118079126) page 23. Below is the C Program which I am referring to, it takes user input and test for condition `User Input % 853 == 83`. I am trying out this example on a 64bit Linux machine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int valid_serial(char *psz){

    size_t len = strlen(psz);
    unsigned total = 0;

    if (len<0){
        return 0;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++){

        if(psz[i] < '0' || psz[i] > 'z'){
            return 0;
        }
        total += psz[i];
    }
    if (total % 853 == 83){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
int validate_serial(){

    char serial[24];
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", serial);

    if(valid_serial(serial)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int do_valid_stuff(){
    printf("The entered serial number is valid\n");
    exit(0);
}

int do_invalid_stuff(){
    printf("The entered serial number is Invalid\n");
    exit(1);
}
int main(void){

    if (validate_serial()){
        do_valid_stuff();
    }
    else{
        do_invalid_stuff();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile the above program and also turning off the stack protector using `gcc -g -fno-stack-protector serial.c -o serial` and as expected the program does work fine

```
$ printf "HHHHHHHHHHHHH" | ./serial
The entered serial number is valid
$ printf "1234" | ./serial
The entered serial number is Invalid
```

Q1) How to enter hex values in GDB?

In GDB I create breakpoints at the following lines

```
line 31          fscanf(stdin, "%s", serial);
line 33          if (valid_serial(serial));
```

At the first breakpoint line 31 this is what I have

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555554912 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000555555554913 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000555555554916 <+4>: mov    eax,0x0
   0x000055555555491b <+9>: call   0x555555554899 <validate_serial>
   0x0000555555554920 <+14>:    test   eax,eax
   0x0000555555554922 <+16>:    je     0x555555554930 <main+30>
   0x0000555555554924 <+18>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000555555554929 <+23>:    call   0x5555555548de <do_valid_stuff>
   0x000055555555492e <+28>:    jmp    0x55555555493a <main+40>
   0x0000555555554930 <+30>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000555555554935 <+35>:    call   0x5555555548f8 <do_invalid_stuff>
   0x000055555555493a <+40>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000055555555493f <+45>:    pop    rbp
   0x0000555555554940 <+46>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/20xg $rsp
0x7fffffffe4f0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffe500: 0x0000555555554950  0x00005555555546c0
0x7fffffffe510: 0x00007fffffffe520  0x0000555555554920
0x7fffffffe520: 0x0000555555554950  0x00007ffff7a5a2b1
0x7fffffffe530: 0x0000000000040000  0x00007fffffffe608
0x7fffffffe540: 0x00000001f7b9b2e8  0x0000555555554912
0x7fffffffe550: 0x0000000000000000  0x9eeb30dff32f3990
0x7fffffffe560: 0x00005555555546c0  0x00007fffffffe600
0x7fffffffe570: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffe580: 0xcbbe658aabef3990  0xcbbe753e255d3990
(gdb)
```

So, at the next step i will have to overwrite the return address of `validate_serial` `0x0000555555554920` with the address of the `call` instruction to `do_valid_stuff` which is `0x0000555555554929`
Continuing gdb

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)IUUUU

Breakpoint 2, validate_serial () at serial.c:33
33      if(valid_serial(serial)){
```

Which successfully overwrites the return address

```
(gdb) x/20xg $rsp
0x7fffffffe4f0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffe500: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffe510: 0x4141414141414141  0x0000555555554929
0x7fffffffe520: 0x0000555555554950  0x00007ffff7a5a2b1
0x7fffffffe530: 0x0000000000040000  0x00007fffffffe608
0x7fffffffe540: 0x00000001f7b9b2e8  0x0000555555554912
0x7fffffffe550: 0x0000000000000000  0x9eeb30dff32f3990
0x7fffffffe560: 0x00005555555546c0  0x00007fffffffe600
0x7fffffffe570: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffe580: 0xcbbe658aabef3990  0xcbbe753e255d3990
(gdb) c
Continuing.
The entered serial number is valid
[Inferior 1 (process 9851) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

I am unable to overwrite the address to 0x0000555555554929 using the below method.

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x29\x49\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00
(gdb) x/20xg $rsp
0x7fffffffe4f0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffe500: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffe510: 0x4141414141414141  0x3934785c3932785c
0x7fffffffe520: 0x3535785c3535785c  0x3535785c3535785c
0x7fffffffe530: 0x3030785c3030785c  0x00007fffffffe600
0x7fffffffe540: 0x00000001f7b9b2e8  0x0000555555554912
0x7fffffffe550: 0x0000000000000000  0xb17102b2c99239fc
0x7fffffffe560: 0x00005555555546c0  0x00007fffffffe600
0x7fffffffe570: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffe580: 0xe42457e7915239fc  0xe42447531fe039fc
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

Q2) Even with the below method I am unable to overwrite the return address. Is it because of ASLR?

```
$ printf "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x29\x49\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00" | ./serial
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: yes, the objective is to replace the return address of `validate_serial` with the address at which the call instruction of `do_valid_stuff()` is located.

Comment: Neither gdb nor scanf parse `\x` style escapes. You can use a pipe or a file.

Comment: GDB disables ASLR, so the only test where you used the shell's `printf` to process `\x` escapes was the one where you ran the program with ASLR enabled.

Comment: Q1: Note that even when your program is running inside GDB, when it reads from the terminal GDB gets out of the way and lets the program read directly.  So you're not "entering hex values in GDB", you're typing them into your program running on the terminal.  After the `read` system call returns (which scanf eventually uses under the hood), or after `scanf` itself returns, you could then use `gdb`'s `set` command to modify memory contents using hex constants.